# Can I say "I applied for a job" and "I applied for my friend", both using the same preposition?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, syntax

- I applied for a job. (Sense of 'for'=asked for something in writing)
- I applied for my friend. (Sense of 'for'=on behalf of)

Are those sentence correct?

Can I use 'for' in this way, because already a fixed preposition is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can "apply for someone" meaning "on their behalf". It just implies that the thing you're applying for is elided.

> — Congratulations, honey! You got the waiter job!
>
>  — Huh? I didn't even apply for it.
>
>  — Oh, I applied for you. I figured it was about time you started working during the summers.
>
>  — *Mo-om!!*

By the way, the sense you supply for "for" in the first case doesn't make sense. It has nothing to do with writing. If you want to supply a synonym for that "for", it would be "to request".

Comment: "Oh, I applied for you. I figured it was about time you started working during the summers."                   What this sentence is trying to express?

Comment: @Ase A common trope in North America: when a teenager gets old enough, their parents want them to hold part-time jobs during the summers between school terms. Since teens rarely want to spend their summers this way, it seemed like a good opportunity to use "apply for" in the sense of "on someone's behalf" :)

Comment: Ok, it was right time, when he should work, so his friend did it on his behalf. Am i Right?

Comment: @Ase Yup, but "Mo-om!!" indicates it was his mom who applied.